# Reading log file during run time and displaying line by line at client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, sitecore, log4net

A log file (log4net) is getting created by clicking on a button. I need to read that file during run time only and display the result line by line to the client end, mostly like a progress bar. How to achieve this? I am using asp.net 4.5, c#

I tried calling some java script function from server side, but obviously it is showing only final result. It has to be simultaneous process.

Comment: This [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/758633/streaming-logs-with-signalr) gives an Idea with NLog and SignalR. Maybe you can adapt it to log4Net?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a memoryappender to your logconfiguration, this will also log to the memory so you dont need to read the file in the same time. Configuration can be done Via the xml config or via code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Attaches a memory appender
/// </summary>
/// <param name="log"></param>
public static MemoryAppender AttachMemoryAppender(this ILog log)
{
    var memoryAppender = new log4net.Appender.MemoryAppender
    {
        //  *** AppenderSkeleton ***
        Name = log.GetLogger().Name,
        Threshold = log.GetLogger().Repository.LevelMap["DEBUG"],

        //  *** MemoryAppender ***
        Fix = FixFlags.All
    };

    var layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout
    {
        ConversionPattern = "%date - %-5level - %message%newline"
    };

    layout.ActivateOptions();
    memoryAppender.Layout = layout;
    memoryAppender.ActivateOptions();

    log.GetLogger().AddAppender(memoryAppender);

    return memoryAppender;
}
```

to get the logs use:

```
var events = memoryAppender.GetEvents();
```